# What are the rules I should follow to ensure GetHashCode() method returns unique value for an object?

Tags: c#, .net, gethashcode

What are the rules I should follow to ensure GetHashCode() method returns unique value for an object?

For example:

- Should I include some prive members for the calculation?
- Should I multiply instead of sum?
- Can I be sure that I am generating a uniqe hash code for a particular object graph? etc.

Comment: Stop. How many instances of `String` are there? How many instances of `int` are there? What is the return type of `String.GetHashCode`? Do you see the problem?

Comment: Based on your previous question you shoul leave GetHashCode() et al alone. First ask _when_ to mess with it. And don't post a question, plenty already here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't even *aim* for `GetHashCode()` returning a unique value for each object. That's not the *point* of `GetHashCode()`.

Eric Lippert has a [great post about hash codes](http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/) which you should read thoroughly. Basically you want to end up with something which will always return the same value for two *equal* objects (and you need to work out what you mean by equal) and is *likely* to return different values for two non-equal objects.

Personally I tend to use an implementation like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 17;
    hash = hash * 31 + field1.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + field2.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + field3.GetHashCode();
    ...
    return hash;
}
```

Things to watch out for:

- If you have mutable objects, be careful! You shouldn't mutate an object after using it as the key in a hash map.
- If your fields can be null, you need to check for that while calculating your hash. For example:

  ```
  hash = hash * 31 + (field2 == null ? 0 : field2.GetHashCode());
  ```

Comment: I will definetely read the article; but the idea is to feed the logic with prime numbers as far as I see. Maybe a very stupid question but do you know if there is way to calculate the most safest prime number canditate for such a scenerio? Thanks!

Comment: @pencilCake: Safest? Safest against what? If two objects create the same hash code, everything will still work - it'll just take *slightly* longer to differentiate between the keys.

Comment: I will read the article first; seems I am not on the same page with you. Thanks Jon!

Comment: @pencilCake: If you are worried about an attacker taking advantage of a weakness in your hash code then no prime number is the *right* prime number. What you have to do in that case is design a hashing algorithm that changes its own parameters in such a way that the attacker cannot craft a data set that causes many collisions. That's for advanced players only; if this is a situation you actually face then hire a professional who deals with such scenarios and knows how to do it right.

Comment: @Eric Lipert: By the way, your article Jon mentioned was really useful for me! Thanks for that!

Comment: @pencilCake: Glad it helped! To address your question about prime numbers: there is a bit of a black art to choosing good hash functions. My advice is to pick a hash function, generate a large body of realistic data, start making dictionaries of reasonable size, and see if the performance is **acceptable**. If not, try varying the algorithm parameters.  No point in tuning a hash algorithm that is already good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a fool proof hashcode because you also need to override Equals for comparison. Usually what I do is take the values I know are different across objects, concatenate them into a string and return the hash for that.

Comment: I've always been curious about the performance characteristics of this form of hash generation vs the sort that Jon mentioned in his answer.

Comment: It really depends you would have to test it. I find this a "trivial" or easy way to do it if you just need a generic hash function that is probably going to be relatively close to unique. So I tend to just have a line like ("" + member_a + member_b + member_c).HashCode(); and I've never had issues with it but this is a quick and dirty way of doing it :P

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here: See Jon Skeet answer, generally pretty reliable way to calculate it. Proved by time :)

[What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)