# Website Speeding down due to matching long strings for Redirect301 URLs - from table containing 1939 records

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, c#-4.0

my website is speeding down due to delay in response from my Redirect301 URLs which i have saved in a table. Whenever any URL of my website is accessed, first i search OLD Url from Redirect301 table containg 1939 rows, this matching is slowing down my website.
Maximum lenght of URL in OldURl column is 129 characters
Average visit of my site is 1000 visits per day.

How i can speed up my website ? Please provide a solution or suggest any one of the following options.

Option 1. By placing this table in a DataTable, and cache this it in memory?

Option 2. By computing hashcode of OLD URL, and then compute HashCode of accessed URL, match it with OLDURL Column and redirect to NEW URL ? but GetHashCode() always does not generates same value , and also two different strings can have same HashCode... please refer to below three URLs

[Can I Use GetHashCode for All string Compares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366828/can-i-use-gethashcode-for-all-string-compares)

[C Sharp - Equals and GetHashCode](http://kenneththorman.blogspot.com/2010/09/c-net-equals-and-gethashcode.html)

[Guidelines and Rules For GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx)

WebServer: IIS7

Database MS SQL Server 2005. Full Text Indexing and searching is installed and working

Option 3. By Computing MD5 Hash according to Option 2?

Option 4. Apply full text index and use Contains to match record.

```
Select NewURL from Redirec301 where contains(OLDURL,"http://www.MySite.Com/OLD-URL")
```

Thanks and Best Regards

Redirect301 Table Of My Database:
[image: Redirect301 Table Of My Database]

Redirect301 Table Structure Details:
[image: Redirect301 Table Structure Details]

Comment: How have you measured the delay and determined that the Redirect301-thingie is responsible?

Comment: I have measured performance via www.NewRelic.com tool, redirect301 query response time is 5 to 8 ms. regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am using  following way and its working good

In ApplicationStart event - i have created Dictionary for all my URLs, with OLD URL as Key, and new URL as value.
Have put this dictionary in application variable

Now i call a method on being-request which checks checks this dictionary for Old_Url